# The difference between tnsping and telnet?

Tags: oracle, tnsping

I'm facing some concerns about tnsping & telnet in Oracle. In my current understanding:

- `telnet IP PORT` is used to test that you can connect to that
  machine (at IP addr) and some service is listening at that PORT.
- `tnsping NET_SERVICE_NAME [COUNT]` is used to test that you can
  connect to that machine (at IP addr) and some service is listening at
  that PORT & that service is an Oracle Listener.

Can someone with a solid knowledge about Oracle verify or point out wrong things in my statements? It is currently hanging in my head, but I am not sure that I have a correct understanding about it.

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong. telnet is far more than just testing that you can connect and a service is listening. Did you try googling *What is telnet*? Telnet lets you actually log into another system and perform operations. Ping lets you know that another system is available at an IP address. tnsping lets you know that an IP address is responding that is associated with an Oracle instance.

Comment: "that is associated with an Oracle instance" is not correct. tnsping test that you can "reach" to LISTENER but not the service it is handling (means reach an Oracle instance).

Comment: Fine. There's still no comparison between what telnet and tnsping do. Google *telnet* to find out what it does, and *ping* to find out what it does. tnsping does what ping does but is specific to Oracle. Your understanding is still incorrect.

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't be using telnet now anyway; you should be using `ssh` instead, as that encrypts transmitted data.

Answer (score 0):

Tnsping .. uses tnsnames.ora file to connect to the oracle instance.
Tnsping on the other hand must get a response from Oracle
Net service or daemon running on the server.

Comment: tnsping doesn't always use tnsnames.ora, for instance, you can: tnsping IP_address:Port and they work fine. The second thing is tnsping don't connect to instance, they do connect to Listener process.

Comment: Yes you right on that ...thats the bequesth protocol it uses....and yes the listener process itself can run on some different server.